# MAMP loads pages very slowly UNLESS I'm logged in as admin

Tags: macos, osx-lion, mamp

**I am NOT using .local addresses** for my sites. It takes almost a minute for pages to load! Basically unusable. I didn't have this problem when I was running MAMP (not pro) on Snow Leopard.

I tried changing some of the syntax in the /etc/hosts file [see below for details]. This worked initially. But then I was crawling again. I just edited `/etc/hosts` again and the pages load quickly again. So editing `/etc/hosts` seems to make a difference...

**IMPORTANT CLUE:**
Whenever I edit /etc/hosts manually, **I have to login as an admin** (sudo?) to make changes. For the next couple minutes my pages are super quick. Then I guess my sudo credentials expire and I go back to loading pages at a snails pace.

**The question:** why does MAMP care if I'm currently sudo or not, and what can I do to make my MAMP sites load quickly all the time?

(I'm running:
MAMP Pro v 2.0.5
OSX Lion v 10.7.4
Chrome v 21.0.1180.82
FireFox v 14.0.1)

NOTE: The changes I initially made to /etc/hosts were from...

```
127.0.0.1 devsite1.dev
127.0.0.1 devsite2.dev
127.0.0.1 devsite3.dev
```

...to...

```
127.0.0.1 devsite1.dev devsite2.dev devsite3.dev
```

Initially I thought it worked, but I later realized the changes weren't making the difference. Just the fact that I had to enter the admin password. I can reproduce these results just by adding/deleting a blank line.

Comment: What exactly are you changing in the hosts file? Don't tease us... c'mon... dish!

Comment: I don't have to change anything! I can just add a blank line. Anything to force the prompt for me to enter my admin password.

Comment: @MarcB I updated the bottom of the question with more details about what I was trying to do when I discovered the magical properties of entering the admin password.

Comment: What is your application actually doing?  Perhaps the problem is not MAMP but something in your application code that is timing out (a `curl` or remote fetch?).  Have you tried isolating the problem?  Test with a simple HTML page, then an interpreted page (eg. a "helloworld.php"), etc.

Comment: @Stennie Great idea! I don't seem to see a difference between HTML and PHP generated pages, but in the course of experimenting I **do** notice that the super slow page load happens immediately after I change something in the PHP file. Maybe this is a "red herring" that has more to do with browser caching, but it's progress. Any ideas where to go next with this info?

By the way, the applications I work on are almost always Wordpress powered sites.